# select a single unique record in a column if records are duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

select a single unique record in a column if records are duplicate

---

we a class table

```
c_id
timing
```

we have records as `(c_id,timing)` values

```
1  |  3-5
2  |  5-7
3  |  3-5
4  |  7-9
5  |  9-11
6  |  11-1
7  |  7-9
```

we select all timing but we have 3-5 and 7-9 timing record 2 times when we select the timing it show only 1 time and other timing show like

```
3-5
5-7
7-9
9-11
11-1
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.  We need to see some effort.  Also what RDBMS are you using?  MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: If you just want unique timings, use `SELECT timing from class_Table group by timing`

Comment: Mark as answer to my response below then.  Just a simple `group by`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is just the unique `timing` then use:

```
SELECT timing from class_Table group by timing
```

Unless there's other information you are trying to get from this query.  Is there any additional info you can give us?